# Java: Programatic Way to Determine Current Windows User

Tags: java, windows

I see many similar questions, however I want to find the Username of the currently logged in user using Java.

Its probably something like:

```
System.getProperty(current.user);
```

But, I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're actually really close. This is what you're looking for:

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

Answer (score 5):

The commonly available system properties are documented in the [`System.getProperties()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) method.

As Chris said `"user.name"` is the property to get the user running your app.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above (and linked for Java 6), to get the current user:

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

For Java 7:  [System.getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)

For Java 8:  [System.getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--)

For Java 9:  [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--)

For Java 10: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--)

For Java 11: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)

For Java 12: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)

For Java 13: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)

For Java 14: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)

For Java 15: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)

For Java 16: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)

For Java 17: [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html)