# How to use Windows login for single-sign-on and for Active Directory entries for Desktop Java application?

Tags: java, active-directory, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I'd like to have my desktop Java application to have single sign on related to 
Active Directory users. In two steps, I'd like to:

1. Be sure that the particular user has logged in to Windows with some user entry.
2. Check out some setup information for that user from the Active Directory

With [Java: Programatic Way to Determine Current Windows User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394/java-programatic-way-to-determine-current-windows-user) I can get the name of the current Windows user but can I rely to that? I think the

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

won't be secure enough? ("user.name" seems to be got from environment variables, so I can't rely on that, I think?)

Question [Authenticating against Active Directory with Java on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390150/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-java-on-linux)
provides me the authentication for given name+pass but I'd like to authenticate based on the Windows logon?

For the Active Directory access, LDAP would probably be the choice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not supported.  Java 6 has improvements, but not enough yet.

Java has its own GSS stack. The problem is for single sign-on, you need to get the Kerberos ticket from the OS (not the Java stack). Otherwise the user has to authenticate a second time (defeating the purpose of single sign-on).

Look at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/. Look down for "Access Native GSS-API" and it talks about a new system property sun.security.jgss.native which when set to true causes Java to use the underlying OS GSS implementation, giving access to the OS level authentication. Perfect!.... except its only supported for Solaris and Linux, not Microsoft Windows.

Java 6 however does appear to have enough support for acting as a *server* receiving SPNEGO authentication requests from IE and then authenticating that user against Active Directory. Its just the desktop client support that is still incomplete.

Comment: Does any other JVM provide access to the Kerberos ticket as described?

Comment: It seems that Java 8 has that support, though. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/jgss-features.html

Answer (score 5):

Use [JAAS](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html) with an [LDAP LoginModule](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html). This will allow you to plug-into the underlying Java security infrastructure.

When you need to take the app offline or "debug" the app, you can easily swap-out the LDAP module for a dummy module.  This allows you to continue testing your "security", without depending on Active Directory. Highly testable, decoupled, and you can the authentication scheme at a later time with almost no grief.

Comment: Thanks,

Does that support authentication by Windows login? (So that when the user is logged to Windows, he/she doesn't have to enter username&password for the java application separately) At first I didn't find that, got to keep on looking still.

Comment: Hmmm. The only modules I've seen that do that are part of a bigger framework like WebLogic... or are design for the Java client to pass credentials to a Web Server. You may have to write a small JAAS Provider using native calls to do this reliably.

Comment: Instead of using LDAP LoginModule, the Krb5LoginModule seems to be able to use OS ticket cache (the credentials got on Windows logon) when used with parameter useTicketCache. There seem still to be some issues, but this works for now on..

Answer (score 4):

Project [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com) has both client and server-side code to do SSO on Windows. It's JNA-based, no native libraries required.

Answer (score 0):

Check jCifs at http://jcifs.samba.org/

Other than that, stick with LDAP (actually, it should be my first try, but...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the JNA api (allows you to do native calls to the operating system easy)?

You can call the win32 metod `GetCurrentUser` MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx. It's located inside Advapi32.dll.

It also has a unicode version, GetCurrentUserW if needed.

And you are right. It does seem that the environment variable can be changed, so that can be misleading to use.

I'm not sure about cross platform implications over 32/64bit windows. 
If you need the solution in code, I'm sure I could write something up for it.

But yea, just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get most flexibility by using [Spring Security](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/index.html). You can use it with both JAAS and LDAP authentication.